# No puedo cargar div de una pagina web externa

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando cargar contenido de una pagina web a otra.
Tengo este script, cuando lo utilizo con una pagina que esta en la misma carpeta funciona, pero si lo hago con alguna como wwwpuntoloqueseapuntocom no  me trabaja.

El siguiente código funciona:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#load').click(function(evt){
      $('#loadcontent').load('prueba.txt')
    })
  })
</script>
```

El siguiente código no funciona:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#load').click(function(evt){
      $('#loadcontent').load(Ejemplo 'HTTP://wwwpuntoloqueseapuntocom/prueba.txt')
    })
  })
</script>
```

Ya tengo la librería de jquery cargada.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y la web externa existe?

Comment: Es posible que el browser lo prohibe.  Me parece que es como "cross-site scripting" lo cual es un tipo de hacking.

Comment: Lo de el navegador esta resuelto, Firefox me lo permite, solo es cuando solicito datos de cualquier web en internet